# Clear recent items list. Not displayed in Windows 7

Tags: context-menu

I use a translator.
A few hours ago, I lost the line "**Clear recent items list**" - ("**Очистить список последних документов**") from the **context menu**, tried to search in the registry, but could not find how to return the line to its place. For a more visual example, I'll attach a screenshot (I couldn't find the English version of my problem). I understand the registry a little, if anyone knows how to fix this problem, please tell me.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDmnR.png)